# Move partition to end of disk

Tags: partition, parted

I have a VM on Promox running Debian 11. I need to increase disk space, so I've resized disk in Proxmox GUI. But now, I need to enlarge root partition.
This wouldn't be a problem, if root partition was the last on disk, but now, it's a partition in the middle of the disk. There is a swap partition that needs to be moved to the end of the disk, before I can resize the root partition. But there are two conditions to be fulfilled:

1. The swap partition has to keep the same size
2. The final swap partition has to be aligned properly to disk layout

As I'm working on a headless, we have to use CLI. This is, what parted give me:

```
(parted) print
Model: QEMU QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 68.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                        bios_grub
 2      2097kB  33.3GB  33.3GB  ext4
 3      33.3GB  34.4GB  1022MB  linux-swap(v1)        swap

(parted) print free
Model: QEMU QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 68.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
        17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Free Space
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                        bios_grub
 2      2097kB  33.3GB  33.3GB  ext4
 3      33.3GB  34.4GB  1022MB  linux-swap(v1)        swap
        34.4GB  68.7GB  34.4GB  Free Space
```

I know, that I have to remove the existing swap partition, using `swapoff /dev/sda3` and deleting it in parted.

My question is: What do I have to type in for creating a properly aligned swap partition with exactly the same size at the end of this disk?

BTW: I don't want top replace Swap with a file.

Comment: I know how to go with that solution, but I prefer a Swap partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can align by using flags like this:

```
parted /dev/sda --align optimal
```

and then setting the units as your first step

```
unit MiB
print
```

Personally I have a script called `pdisk` that handles this and I run `parted` non-interactively:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
dev="$1"
shift
test 0 -eq $# && set -- print
parted "$dev" --align optimal unit MiB "$@"
```

And then

```
pdisk /dev/sda [<command>]
```